# Extracting 'duration' metadata from multiple audio files

Tags: javascript, audio, metadata, duration

I'm a newbie trying to do something in JavaScript that I thought would be simple, but I'm having huge problems with timing. I have a list of audio tracks (3 for the purposes of this example, but it can be any number) and I want to extract the 'duration' metadata from each of the files. I need the final code to fit inside an existing 'for' loop which is processing other data relating to each audio.

In experiments, I can get the duration for a single audio file, as shown by the log :-

```
loading track1.mp3  
Meta data for audio 1 loaded  
duration of audio 1 = 390.321633 seconds
```

However, if I wrap my code in a 'for' loop, I only get the duration for the last file in the list, and this happens after the for loop has finished executing.

```
loading track1.mp3  
loading track2.mp3  
loading track3.mp3  
Meta data for audio 4 loaded  
duration of audio 4 = 286.171429 seconds
```

I've experimented using various permutations of functions, nested functions and attempts with callbacks (which I'm still having problems comprehending), but I'm hopelessly lost.

Can anyone offer a JavaScript-only solution (preferably with comments to help my understanding of what's being done)? I'd prefer not to use Jquery, so that I'm not trying to understand and learn learn two things at once, but if using it is the only solution, then so be it.

Here's my code

```
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
<script>
var aud1 = document.createElement("audio");
aud1.id="audio1";
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(aud1);
aud1.controls=true;
aud1.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  console.log("Meta data for audio "+a+" loaded");
  var d = document.getElementById("audio1");
  console.log("duration of audio " + a + " = " + d.duration + " seconds");
}
for (a=1;a<4;a++) {
  console.log("loading track" + a + ".mp3")
  aud1.src="track"+a+".mp3";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
Replaced the for loop with a simple counter, updated within the event handler.

```
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
<script>
var a=0;
var aud1 = document.createElement("audio");
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(aud1);
aud1.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    console.log("Meta data for audio "+a+" loaded");
    var d = document.getElementById("audio1");
    console.log("duration of audio "+a+" = " + d.duration + " seconds");
    a++
if(a===3)return
console.log("loading track"+a+".mp3");
aud1.src="track"+a+".mp3";
};
aud1.id="audio1";
aud1.controls=true;
aud1.autoplay = false;
console.log("loading track"+a+".mp3");
aud1.src="track"+a+".mp3";
</script>
</body>
```

This now gives the correct sequence :-

```
loading track0.mp3  
Meta data for audio 0 loaded  
duration of audio 0 = 390.321633 seconds  
loading track1.mp3  
Meta data for audio 1 loaded  
duration of audio 1 = 303.882449 seconds  
loading track2.mp3  
Meta data for audio 2 loaded  
duration of audio 2 = 286.171429 second
```